# No permission to write error Cordova Android

Tags: android, cordova

I am getting a error when i try save a file on cordova in android it says no permission to write aborted i am using window window.saveAs(blob, "MinecraftModel.json"); it works fine on the browser why wont it write to android?

heres my file save code:

```
 $("#export-techne").click(function() {
            var result = JSON.stringify(window.techne.exportTechneModel());
            var blob = new Blob([result], {type: "application/json"});

            window.saveAs(blob, "TechneModel.json");
            writeToFile('example.json', { foo: result });
            //$("#exportLabel").text("Minecraft Block (json)");
            //$("#exportModal pre").text(result);
            //$('#exportModal').modal();
        });
```

and here is my permissions in the androidmanafest xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Android requires permissions to write to device. not sure how this is done in Cordova but a quick google search should fix it.

Comment: ive got the  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> it still has that error

Comment: Please show some of your code to better help you. specially your permissions and saving file code.

Comment: Try using this code https://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/11/05/Cordova-Example-Writing-to-a-file/ I think `Window.saveas()` is not supported.

Comment: @Qbotindustries window.saveas() seems to be not working in Android webview. Better include cordova file plugin and try writing file using the plugin in device which is guaranteed to work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this permission?

Xwalk for Android need this permission (and also some configurations on the Initializer) beacuse the Download Function is Inherited from the main class. It is not an directly android function. So the OS takes this download as an silent update of the app, or even more especific, it takes as an aditional file.

It been years from you asked for this, I hope it still helps.

Comment: Jonas What is the permission?